# c# decompress json from php gzcompress

Tags: c#, php, gzip

I'm having a problem unpacking the POST call that I send to my PHP service.

PHP generates an array encoded in json and compressed via the (gzcompress).

**PHP**

```
$data = gzcompress(json_encode($resultArray),6);
echo $data;
```

I try to decompress it in c# to get a json string.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not let the web server handle the compression?

Comment: compression is managed by the web server using api php and mysql. The result in json of a query is compressed ... Now my app receives this result which it needs to decompress

Comment: How is C# involved here? You say you try to decompress it in C#, but you aren't explaining how you suddenly jump from PHP to C#.